# Child directives API function getting added to childHead

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Just came across a interesting issue, following is the fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/gauravsoni/L9us7etq/1/

The 'commbase' directive calls the 'showmessage' directive, both of them are using ng-if to show some template.

The 'showmessage' directive has a API function called `showAlert`. The issue is if i call the showmessage within a ng-if (line 20) , the function showAlert cannot be called as it has moved to the $$childHead. Now, everything works fine if i remove ng-if or use ng-show.

It seems that a new scope is created when using ng-if , how can this be solved ? or is there some better way to show public API's so its directly present in the parents scope every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so what i did was instead of binding the api function directly to the parents $scope , I bonded it to the parent controller.

So my attr that exposed the API fns looks like this. `apis='commbaseCtrl.secondapi'` where the commbaseCtrl is the name of the parent controller.